# preg_match length width height

Tags: php, preg-match

I open a csv-file in php and I do have columns with multiple rows that looks like this:

```
1 | Some word 18x140x2000mm another word
2 | 20x150x300cm couple other words
3 | new words 30x140x2100mm
```

How do I get with preg_match the length, height, width in the string and even the unit cm, mm.

```
1 | $attributes = array(18, 140, 2000, mm);
2 | ...
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have You Try This?**

```
(\d+)x(\d+)x(\d+)(\w+)
```

please let me know if it doesn't work..

Comment: But how do I create the array();? THANKS FOR HELP!

Comment: m not sure  but try this $attributes = array[];

Comment: Oh, sorry, - preg_match($search, $input, $out); THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @craphunter please approve my answer if it helped you  :) thank you